# How to correctly setText() at first, then listen onTextChanged()?

Tags: android, rx-android

I want `setText()` at first, then `addTextChangedListener()` for listen `onTextChanged()`.

Such as:

```
val textFromIntent = activity.intent.getStringExtra("KEY_TEXT")

// Don't need listen this call which is from Intent
editTextView.setText(textFromIntent)

// Need listen the other changes which are user edit.
editTextView.addTextChangedListener(listener)
```

I know I can `return` in `onTextChanged()` when the first change, any good ideas?

Comment: what's wrong with that code?

Answer (score 0):

the code you have written will work exactly the way you want ,
however if you want to use setText after adding listener you can use following:

```
        editTextView.removeTextChangedListener(listener)
```

// Don't need listen this call which is from Intent
        editTextView?.setText(textFromIntent)

// Need listen the other changes which are user edit.
        editTextView?.addTextChangedListener(listener)

Answer (score 0):

```
editTextView.addTextChangedListener(null)
editTextView.setText(text)
editTextView.addTextChangedListener(listener)
```